# Creating an RSS feed from multiple RSS feeds

Tags: rss, if-this-then-that, rss-reader

I use [Blogtrottr](https://blogtrottr.com/subscriptions/) to receive RSS feed updates to my email inbox. However, it only allows me to create one email digest for one RSS feed.

What I am thus looking for is a way to create an RSS feed from multiple RSS feeds combined that I can then feed to Blogtrottr.

Does anyone know how to automate this technique using IFTTT to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [RSS Mix](http://www.rssmix.com/) I have used it and I'm very satisfied and happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using [Feedspot RSS Reader](http://www.feedspot.com). It offers a 1 year 'pro' trial that allows me to create a [unique RSS Feed URL for a folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAHrF.png) that can contain multiple RSS feeds. This feed URL in turn can be fed to Blogtrottr to receive daily digests from multiple RSS feeds in just one email.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could achieve this using IFTTT.

You could set up an email alert for each RSS feed using the [Feed channel](https://ifttt.com/feed) as a trigger and the [Email channel](https://ifttt.com/email) as the action.

You could receive a daily or weekly digest by using the Feed channel as a trigger and the Email Digest channel as the action.

Or you could use a service like Feedly as the trigger, in which case any RSS feed item in a Feedly category could be sent in a single or a digest email.

Comment: You can see plenty of example 'recipes' at the [IFTTT website](https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=rss+to+email)

Comment: The `Feed Channel` does not allow me to feed multiple RSS feeds into one. Feedly isn't an option either because it requires a pro license to be used with IFTTT.

Comment: I use Feedly with IFTTT in the way described. I do not have a 'pro license'.

Comment: Does it have to do something with the date of registration of the user account? I get this: http://i.imgur.com/3vw7QtQ.png